# Lightning Experience only for a specific object

Tags: lightning-experience, migration

We are migrating from Classic to [Lightning Experience](https://www.salesforce.com/campaign/lightning/). We are first migrating on our sandbox, then we deploy the changes to production, but once we entirely migrate an object to production, let's say Delivery__c object, we only want to show that object in [Lightning Experience](https://www.salesforce.com/campaign/lightning/), and the rest of objects in Classic Experience. Is this possible to accomplish? I checked the entire trail head for [Make the Move to Lightning Experience](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/lex_admin_migration), but I did not find any article related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, the point of lightning is for your whole interface to change. You could create an app with only that object available as a tab, but all the other objects will still be available through the app launcher, or from the add tabs section. I honestly found it a lot easier through setup everything from the preview mode, saved me a lot of time and worked better than going back and forth on Sandboxes.